# Normal subgroup problem involving generating set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the group $GL_2\mathbb (\mathbb C)$ and let $$H=\left<\begin{bmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{bmatrix}\right>.$$

The first thing i want to do is evaluate the 8 elements of H and determine their order, the problem is I've only had to do this for a set H with only one element that generates it, for two elements I assume we times each of the matrix's by themselves until we get the identity element for each one(is this correct)? and then to calculate the order of each of the elements by using Lagrange's theorem?

the second thing i want to do is find all the subgroups of $H$ which i dont know where to start with

Answer (score 2):

Sketch: Let the two generators be $a$ and $b$.  The idea is to keep track of the elements that you know are in the group.

Initially,
$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}.
$$
Then, take each of the elements of the set, and multiply on the right by $a$ and $b$ (try them both individually).  If you get something new, add that element to the set and start over.  When you multiply all the elements by $a$ and $b$ and don't get anything new, you have the entire group.

This helps you find the $8$ elements.  Then, you can study the orders of the elements by computing their powers.  The order of the elements doesn't require Lagrange's theorem.

Once you find the elements and their orders, you can identify the group that you're dealing with and determine the possible types and orders of subgroups that that group has.